# Connection Timeout in Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry-jde, connection-timeout

How to set Connection timeout in blackberry while fetching data using HttpConnection from url?
I was passing ConnectionTimeout parameter in url but not working
When there is no network,blanck screen should be displayed along with network error message.

Comment: I was passing ConnectionTimeout parameter in url but not working

Comment: StreamConnection s = (StreamConnection)Connector.open("http://myserver.com/mypage.html;ConnectionTimeout=60000;deviceside=false");

HttpConnection httpConn = (HttpConnection)s;
I want 45 seconds timeout from request.

Comment: Try this                                                StreamConnection s = StreamConnection)Connector.open("http://www.example.com/mypage.html;ConnectionTimeout=45000;");
HttpConnection httpConn = (HttpConnection)s; How are you specifying the Timeout value in the URL?

Comment: Not working also if i change value... can you tel me how to use timer in such case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387158/timeout-for-blackberry-httpconnection

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Specify-timeout-for-http-connection/m-p/114234/highlight/true#M12943):

> From [DB-00526](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Control-the-connection-timeout-for-TCP-connections-through-the/ta-p/445851):
>
> Note: The ConnectionTimeout parameter is not supported by direct TCP connections or connections through a Wireless Application Protocol (WAP) gateway. Only TCP connections, made through the BlackBerry MDS Connection Service, support this parameter.
>
> I suspect this is the reason for your exception.